# Cannot read length property error in jsonstore in Mobilefirst platform

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to javascript and MobileFirst. I trying to read a list of json values:

```
[{"_id":1,"json":{"age":10,"name":"carlos"}},{"_id":2,"json":{"age":10,"name":"carlos"}}]
```

And output the value in a DOM. It fails and output this error:

> 03-27 04:29:19.035: E/NONE(3093): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o at (compiled_code):311

Here is the function:

### main.js:

```
 function add(){
    var collectionName = 'people';

    // Object that defines all the collections.
    var collections = {

      // Object that defines the 'people' collection.
      people : {

        // Object that defines the Search Fields for the 'people' collection.
        searchFields : {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}
      }
    };

    // Optional options object.
    var options = {


    };

    WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)

    .then(function () {

      // Data to add, you probably want to get
      // this data from a network call (e.g. Worklight Adapter).
      var data = [{name: 'carlos', age: 10}];

      // Optional options for add.
      var addOptions = {

        // Mark data as dirty (true = yes, false = no), default true.
        markDirty: true
      };

      // Get an accessor to the people collection and add data.
      return WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data, addOptions);
    })

    .then(function (numberOfDocumentsAdded) {
      // Add was successful.
        alert("Data successfully added.");
    })

    .fail(function (errorObject) {
        alert("Data failed to be added.");

    });

}
function display(){
var collectionName = 'people';



var options = {
 };

WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName)

.findAll()

.then(function (arrayResults) {
  // arrayResults = [{_id: 1, json: {name: 'carlos', age: 99}}]

    var arrayResult = '{"files":' + arrayResults + '}';
    alert(arrayResults.length);
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(arrayResult);
    alert (jsonData.files.length);
    alert(jsonData);



     var full_list = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.files.length; i++) {
        var file = jsonData.files[i];
        full_list =  full_list + file.json.name + " " + file._id + " is " + file.json.age + '<br />';
        $("#demo").append(full_list); 


    }



})
.fail(function (errorObject) {
  // Handle failure.
});


 }
```

**index.html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="display();" >click here to display the data</a>
        <br /> 
        <a href="#" onclick="deldocument();" >click here to delete the data</a>
        <p id="demo"></p> <br /> 
        <a href="#" onclick="destroy();" >click here to destroy the data</a>
        <p id="demo"></p> <br />
```

I will highly appreciate if i can get some help please. Thank you lots guys.

Comment: Show your complete code, not just a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you **JSON.parse** an object the `"Unexpected token o"` is thrown simply because it tries to parse **obj_to_parse.toString()**, which is `[object Object]`. Try to `JSON.parse('[object Object]')`.

This is your result:

```
//arrayResults = [{_id: 1, json: {name: 'carlos', age: 99}}]
```

Try to read  this way  :

```
       var full_list="";
        for(var i=0;i<arrayResults.length;i++){ 
            // alert(arrayResults[i]._id);
            // alert(arrayResults[i].json.name); 
            // alert(arrayResults[i].json.age);
           full_list =  full_list + arrayResults[i].json.name + " " + arrayResults[i]._id + " is " + arrayResults[i].json.age + '<br />';
        $("#demo").append(full_list);  

         }
```

Comment: Thank you lots. You are the best. xD